# Where is the API for block producer voting in EOSJS?

Tags: voting, javascript, eosjs

I have found the 'system voteproducer' command in cleos. Should I make a raw transaction or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a system contract for voting. It can be found here: 
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp

ABI can be found here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.abi

You can run a `cleos action` command for the system contract:

```
cleos push action eosio voteproducer '["voter", "proxy", ["producers"]]'
```

Answer (score 3):

Call voteproducer..

```
> eos.voteproducer()

CONTRACT
eosio

FUNCTION
voteproducer

PARAMETERS
{
    "voter": "account_name",
    "proxy": "account_name",
    "producers": "account_name[]"
}

EXAMPLE
{
    "voter": "",
    "proxy": "",
    "producers": [
        ""
    ]
}
```

Lookup your account name using your EOS Claim Key.

This is one tool for the job: https://toolkit.genereos.io/tools

> voteproducer.js

```
const {wif} = process.env

// EOS Account
account = 'yourlongacct'

// full list of producers (renew votes and overwrites prior lists)
producers = ['libertyblock']

httpEndpoint = 'https://mainnet.eoscanada.com'

chainId = 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906'

Eos = require('eosjs')
eos = Eos({httpEndpoint, chainId, keyProvider: wif})
eos.voteproducer(account, proxy = '', producers,
  (error, result) => { console.log(error, result) })
```

If using nodejs, some bash consoles are setup to omit history if you start a command with a space.  With this configured a private key
can be provided in a way that it will not be cached on disk.

```
# check it
echo $HISTCONTROL 
ignoreboth

# or set it
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# test it
 echo 1
[up arrow]
```

Setup for the script above:

```
mkdir eosjs && cd eosjs
npm init --yes && npm i eosjs
```

vote:

```
# start with a space to keep wif out of history
 wif=yourPrivateWif node voteproducer.js
```